# Django store aggregated data in the database?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a use case where I have some complex functions (involving aggregations) that take a few seconds to run, and are affecting the UX of the app (even when the rows are just about 25-30k and the relevant fields are indexed). I am thinking of storing the aggregations in the database itself (and run them nightly) since real-time-liness of the data is not very important here. Is that a common practice with Django?

(I couldnt find much discussion on that on SO though)

Comment: You should store result in cache system like Memcache or redis. You can check https://github.com/niwinz/django-redis

Comment: You may want to use some sort of materialized view (depends on your db), and then create a unmanaged model in django to query it.

Comment: You should just use any caching system, as @ittus said.

Comment: You should to create new models/fields for aggregate data and figure up it nightly though a [django custom comand](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/) or a celery task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do you have several options:**

- [@ittus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2303610/ittus)'s and [@Andrey Shipilov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/375649/andrey-shipilov)'s  approach: store result in cache system like Memcache or redis. You can check [github.com/niwinz/django-redis](https://github.com/niwinz/django-redis)
- [@Anonymous](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5113242/anonymous)'s approach: use some sort of materialized view (depends on your db), and then create a unmanaged model in django to query it.
- Create new models/fields for aggregate data and figure up it nightly though a [django custom comand](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/) or a celery task.

**Conclusions:**

- Your question should be close because is a primarily opinion-based question, like this one [Django - what is best practice - Calculating field values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33483013/django-what-is-best-practice-calculating-field-values).

**Notice:**

- If you need real time calculation then you can overwrite save method on models to keep data or just connect a post_save signal.